# how to read the PDF file in a line by line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf

i have a problem reading PDF file in python 2.7 line by line
i want to read each line separately and print them, the solutions that have in this site i used before but not working.

I try this code

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('c:\python\anms.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageObj.extractText()
```

but this code extract all strings in PDF i want extract all strings but line by line not all together.

import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('c:\python\anms.pdf','rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

pdfReader.numPages

pageObj =pdfReader.getPage(0)

pageObj.extractText()

but this code extract all strings in PDF i want extract all strings but line by line .

Comment: Show some code what you have tried so far

Comment: You may have better luck downloading a Python library like `pdfminer` and using that to extract text/HTML/XML from the PDF.

Comment: can i read text fro the PDF line by line using Pdfminer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by saving it in a big string

```
text = pageObj.extractText()
```

and then splitting each line

```
lines = text.split("\n")
```

This will save each line as an element in the list `lines`
if you want to print each line just iterate through the list

```
for i in lines:
    print(i)
```